# Assigning TScrollBox event during runtime - incompatible types

Tags: panel, c++builder, tscrollbox, scrollbox

Using RAD Studio 10.4.2:

I create `TScrollBox` during runtime:

```
TScrollBox* sb = new TScrollBox(this);
sb->Parent = this;
sb->Align = alClient;
sb->AlignWithMargins = true;
sb->Margins->SetBounds(3,3,3,3);
sb->BorderStyle = bsNone;
sb->VertScrollBar->Smooth = true;
sb->VertScrollBar->Tracking = true;
sb->ParentBackground = true;
sb->OnMouseWheel = ScrollBox1MouseWheel; // Error here
```

And I want to assign it `OnMouseWheel` event:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ScrollBox1MouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta,
TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
// Some code here
}
```

The mouse wheel event is just the one I got when I placed it on the form and doubleclicked to generate the above event code.

The error is though:

`[bcc32c Error] assigning to 'Vcl::Controls::TMouseWheelEvent' (aka 'void ((__closure *))(System::TObject *, System::Classes::TShiftState, int, const System::Types::TPoint &, bool &) __attribute__((fastcall))') from incompatible type 'void (__closure *)(System::TObject *, System::Classes::TShiftState, int, System::Types::TPoint &, bool &) __attribute__((fastcall))'`

How do I assign the event then, do I need to cast it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself immediately after posting so I am sharing the solution:

I changed the function definition to:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ScrollBox1MouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta,
const TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled) // -> added const here
{
// Some code here
}
```

For some reason 10.4.2 GUI generates the function without the `const` in the TPoint, when you double click from the object inspector, but it expects it when it is being assigned during runtime, so when `const` is added it compiles just fine.